# Equivalent expressions for 'I will reply in the near future' or 'before too long'

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for equivalent expressions for 'In the near future' & 'before too long'. I'd use these terms in the following way

'I will reply to you in the near future (or before too long)'.

I think 'soon' is the basic meaning of the both. So 'soon' is one option. But I'm looking other expressions.

Some research:

> **in the near future**
>
> Very soon, within a short time. For example, We'll be needing a new car in the near future . This term employs near in the sense of “close at hand,” a usage dating from about 1300. Also see at hand , def. 2. The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary.
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27In+the+near+future&oq=%27In+the+near+future&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=in+the+near+future+meaning)
>
> **before too long**
>
> “before too long” figuratively means the exact opposite of “a long time long in the future”. This double negative (which is a form of understatement) is called litotes (thanks to RegDwight for pointing this out). It's the same as saying “not bad” when you actually mean “quite good indeed”.Jan 13, 2011
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=before+too+long&oq=before+too+long&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=before+too+long+meaning)

Comment: Did you happen to consult a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/soon)? On this and other SE sites, [not including the research you've done](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a reason to place the question on hold.

Comment: Not a comment on grammar, but on courtesy: it is much better to give an explicit date before which a response will be given, rather than a vague *soon* or *in the near future* or *eventually* or *when the universe winds down* ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic idiom for this is:

> I'll get back to you
>
> I'll get back to you (on that). and Let me get back to you (on that).
>   I will report back later with my decision. (More likely said by a boss to an employee than vice versa.) Bob: I have a question about the Wilson project. Mary: I have to go to a meeting now. I'll get back to you on that. Bob: It's sort of urgent. Mary: It can wait. Sue: Shall I close the Wilson account? Jane: Let me get back to you on that.
>
> [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I'll+get+back+to+you)

Also comes in acronym form:

> IGBTY
>
> I'll Get Back to You
>
> [thefreedictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27ll+get+back+to+you)

Comment: But 'I'll get back to you' distances the 'soon' assurance. It's further (perhaps not too much further) down the continuum that ends at 'Don't phone us ...'.

Answer (score 1):

[Shortly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortly): in or within a short time.

I will respond to your request shortly.  I'll get back to you shortly.